# 'Hub' is an ambiguous reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm using these libraries in my application:

```
using SignalRDemo.Hubs;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

Now I have to implement `IConnect, IDisconnect` interface. So, I added `using SignalR.Hubs;` 
and added a function in my ChatHub class:

```
   public class ChatHub : Hub, IConnected, IDisconnect
     {
     public Task Connect()
            {
                //Call the joined method on all connected clients
                return Clients.joined(Context.ConnectionId);

            }
     }
```

Client Side Code:

```
chatHub.joined = function (connectionId) {
                $('#connections').append('<li>Connect: ' + connectionId + '</li>');
            }
```

But, when I build the solution it shows an error.

```
   'Hub' is an ambiguous reference between 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hub' and 'SignalR.Hubs.Hub'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have two different assemblies of SignalR in your project. Latest version uses `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR` namespace. Check your assemblies and remove the previous version.

Otherwise you need to tell the compiler which namespace you want to use.

```
public class ChatHub : Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hub
```

**Edit:**

[halter74](https://stackoverflow.com/users/719967/halter73) pointed out that `IConnected` and `IDisconnect` interfaces have been removed. `OnConnected`, `OnDisconnected` and `OnReconnected` virtual methods can be found on Hub Class.

Comment: With the latest versions of SignalR (Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hub), the IConnected and IDisconnect interfaces have been removed. However, OnConnected, OnDisconnected and OnReconnected are virtual methods on the Hub class.

Answer (score 0):

This means what it say. Hub class defined in `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR` and `SignalR.Hubs.Hub` namespaces and you `using` both in your code, so compiler don't know which one to use; You must explicitly define proper class:

```
public class ChatHub : SignalR.Hubs.Hub, IConnected, IDisconnect
```

or

```
using Hub = SignalR.Hubs.Hub;
```